# Whois Terminal script with Automator

Tags: macos, terminal, automator

I'd like to take an IP address from my Terminal, right click, select Services > Whois and get the results back somehow.

This doesn't exist so I'm wanting to create a simple Automator script to do that. But, I'm running into a few problems.

This is what I've done - Automator Actions:

1. Get Specified Text 
   (this will be the IP address)
2. Run Shell Script
   for x in "$@" ; 
   do whois $x; 
   done
3. View Results

But all I get in View Results is this:

```
(
  ""
)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must print the result, use `echo`.

For a single IP address, use "**$@**" instead of using a loop.

```
echo $(whois "$@")
```